# Script Error says Unknown Global although the names are clearly correct

Tags: lua, roblox

[image]

Although the names in the code are correct, the error still says that the names are not correct which makes no sense. I am pretty new to lua script and roblox studio

Comment: Try `local fin = model.fin` instead of `local platform = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local platform = model.Anchor
local platform = model.start
local platform = model.fin
```

Here you assign three different values to a local platform. So the first two lines have no effect.

Then you index `fin` and `start` in

```
local distance = fin.Position - start.Position
```

Where `fin` and `start` have never been defined in local or global scope. Hence the error message.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
local start = model.start
local fin = model.fin
local distance = fin.Position - start.Position
```